# Microsoft Deployment Workbench chocolatey problem

Tags: windows, batch-file, deployment, server, chocolatey

I am currently testing Microsoft Deployment Workbench for automated Windows installation.

I have created a workflow with Windows 11 and would like to install the various programs via chocolatey after the Windows 11 installation.
[image: Workflow Overview]
Here you can see my workflow:

1. chocolatey is installed with a `.bat` script using:

   command line: `cmd.exe /c "%SCRIPTROOT%\BTNHD\chocoinstall.bat"`

   with the following content:

   ```
    @powershell -noProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
   ```
2. then we restart the computer
3. then the script is started with the different programs, which looks like this:

   command line: `cmd.exe /c "%SCRIPTROOT%\BTNHD\installtemplate.bat"`

   with the following content:

   ```
   choco install firefox --yes
   choco install vlc --yes
   ```

Unfortunately it installs only the first software in the list at step 3, in my case Firefox and after that it takes a while and aborts with these  error messages:
[image: Error Codes]

Now I have already tried the following things:

1. the reboot removed unfortunately no improvement
2. for each program a separate script and accordingly a separate installation step
3. tested other programs
4. changed the script

unfortunately there is nothing in the chocolatey log that can help me.

If I start the script manually, but everything works fine.
I currently do not know what to do and hope someone can help me, if there is any information missing, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Update: its only one a specific laptop serie: Dell Precision 3560 on every other normal Windows PC it works. Does anyone know why his want to do on a dell? Of course i tried a other Precision 356, but got the same Issue